# How to convert folder contains text files into xml file for haar training

Tags: xml, opencv, text, cascade

I'm using opencv_haartrainaing to train my cascade classifier, and i've a folder containing sub-folders with text files instead of the .xml file as shown here....

[image]

How can i get the final .xml file?.

Comment: You have shown us the names of 8 folders, but not given us a clue as to what is in them.

Comment: Each one contains text file with name `AdaBoostCARTHaarClassifier`.... i mentioned that in the question header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it : in the command prompt `cmd` use the following line

`convert_cascade --size="20x20" haarcascade haarcascade.xml`

where

`convert_cascade --size="<sample_width>x<sampe_height>" <haartraining_ouput_dir><ouput_file>`

`convert_cascade is a ".c" file in`..\opencv\samples\c`directory, i compiled it in new project to get 'convert_cascade.exe`.

Reference: [Tutorial: OpenCV haartraining](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html)

Comment: ur folder should contain .xml file if not then u will not able to create final xml.